# Bone Constraint/ Location rotation issue

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

Trying to get my model to clench his fist with the location rotation bone constraint however when applied the bone barely rotates at all. Is there something i left out?

Blend file
[image]

Comment: what location rotation bone constraint are you talking about? I don't see any for your fist. Note that your Pivot Point is in 3D Cursor mode, maybe your problem comes from there?

Comment: I may have added the previous blend file. But when i add the constraint and try to rotate it, it moves  very slowly and when i move the bone above the finger tip and warps the entire palm.

Comment: please link the file with the constraint so that we can see the problem

Comment: Sorry disregard you were right its the 3D cursor mode. I didnt know that changed to that nor do i understand how it changed to that because i never touched it. thank you!

Comment: so did it fix your problem?

Comment: Yup it did, the fingers are moving properly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your Pivot Point setting from *3D Cursor* to *Median Point*.